# Split full Name into First Name, Middle Name, Last Name and suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For example
I have a FullName column in a table

```
FullName 
------------------
Smith Johns Sr
James Macoy
Krushit J Patel II
Sheldon Devid
Jeff vandorf Jr
Steve Smith I
```

And I want a result like

```
|FirstName | Middle Name | lastName | Suffix |
|--------------------------------------------|
|Smith     | NULL        | Johns    | Null   |
|James     | NULL        | Macoy    | Null   |
|Krushit   | J           | Patel    | II     |
|Sheldon   | NULL        | Devid    | Null   |
|Jeff      | Null        | vandorf  |Jr      |
|Steve     |Smith        | Ronder   |I       |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Statement to move Name Suffix (Jr, Sr, IV, etc) into another field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711944/tsql-statement-to-move-name-suffix-jr-sr-iv-etc-into-another-field)

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem, particularly since many cultures living in English speaking countries have cultural naming systems where there is not even the concept of "middle name". Take for instance a name like Maria de los Angeles Gomez de la Cruz, or Mary Paul White (is her middle name Paul, or does she have a dual surname?). There is no easy way to correctly do what you want with names normally encountered, because of ambiguities you cannot resolve without more information.

Comment: Any answer to this question would be based off assumptions, primarily your names are always FML with or without a suffix. There are too many possibilities to consider as @hatchet has mentioned. There are dozens of similar questions on SO to this. All answers to those questions are only correct with a never changing, defined variable limitation. So, if your data contains more variations that what you have shown, you are going to have a lot of CASE statements and/or are going to have to go back and forth with someone until all exceptions are handled. Start with finding white spaces, if you dare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 

d.First_Name


,CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ',d.REST_OF_NAME)
       THEN NULL  
       ELSE SUBSTRING(                                                    ---- finds the middle name from rest of the name 
                       d.REST_OF_NAME
                      ,1
                      ,CHARINDEX(' ',d.REST_OF_NAME)-1
                     )
       END AS Middle_Name

,SUBSTRING(
             d.REST_OF_NAME                                             ---- finds the Last name from rest of the name 
            ,1 + CHARINDEX(' ', d.REST_OF_NAME)
            ,LEN( d.REST_OF_NAME)
           ) AS Last_Name

,d.Suffix
,d.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
,D.Orignal_Data_String
from
(SELECT c.Suffix,

CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ',c.Remainding_Name_Part)
         THEN c.Remainding_Name_Part 
         ELSE SUBSTRING(                                                    ---- substring first name fro rest of the name from reminding part of the name 
                         c.Remainding_Name_Part
                        ,1
                        ,CHARINDEX(' ',c.Remainding_Name_Part)-1
                       )
    END AS First_Name
,CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ',c.Remainding_Name_Part)  
         THEN NULL  
         ELSE SUBSTRING(
                         c.Remainding_Name_Part
                        ,CHARINDEX(' ',c.Remainding_Name_Part)+1           ------    substring rest of the name after substracting firstname from the remainding partof the name
                        ,LEN(c.Remainding_Name_Part)
                       )
    END AS REST_OF_NAME

,c.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
,C.Orignal_Data_String
FROM 
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN RIGHT(b.Name,2) IN ('IV','Jr','Sr')
     THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(b.Name,2)))                                     ----finds suffix in name        
        WHEN RIGHT(b.Name,3) IN ('III','Esq',' II')
       THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(b.Name,3))) 

ELSE NULL
END AS [Suffix]
,
CASE WHEN RIGHT(b.Name,2) IN ('IV','Jr','Sr')
     THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(b.name,LEN(b.name)-2)))                         ----finds remider part of name after subtrecting suffix        
       WHEN RIGHT(b.Name,3) IN ('III',' Esq',' II')
       THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(b.name,LEN(b.name)-3)))

ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(b.name))
END AS [Remainding_Name_Part]
,B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
,B.Orignal_Data_String


FROM 

(SELECT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(a.NAME)),'  ',' '),'  ',' ') AS [Name]         ------ Clears spaces 
,A.NAME AS [Orignal_Data_String]
,a.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
FROM 
(
SELECT NAME,CUSTOMER_NUMBER                                                 ------ finds the customers
FROM [FIS_CORE_FEEDS_DM].[dbo].[FIS_DAILY_CUST_TABLE]
WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE !='O'
        )A
     )B
   )C
)D
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, the question is too vague (and the problem described too complex) to be able to give a particularly helpful answer, but I will try anyway.

We can propose a solution if we make some assumptions about the name values you're wanting to split:

- Each name contains between 2 and 4 "words", each separated by a single space
- 2 word names are formed: `[First Name] [Last Name]`
- 3 word names are formed: `[First Name] [Last Name] [Suffix]`
- 4 word names are formed: `[First Name] [Middle Name] [Last Name] [Suffix]`

In this case, we could solve as follows (if our names exist in a table called `names` with a single column called `Name`:

```
SELECT      
 SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Name) - 1) AS FirstName
,CASE LEN(Name) - LEN(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')) + 1
    WHEN 2 THEN NULL
    WHEN 3 THEN NULL
    WHEN 4 THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name))) - 1)
 END AS [Middle Name]
,CASE LEN(Name) - LEN(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')) + 1
    WHEN 2 THEN RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name))
    WHEN 3 THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name))) - 1)
    WHEN 4 THEN SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name) + 1)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Name) + 1))) - 1)
 END AS lastName
,CASE LEN(Name) - LEN(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')) + 1
    WHEN 2 THEN NULL
    WHEN 3 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Name), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) - 1))
    WHEN 4 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Name), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(Name)) - 1))
 END AS Suffix
FROM names
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it illustrates the usage of `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` that can be applied to break down a string like this. There is definitely some redundancy which could be worked out of this query and more elegant ways to implement it (plus it may not suit your dataset because of the assumptions above), but hopefully it's a helpful starting point for you.

A neater solution might be to create a function which takes 2 parameters - a string and an integer to indicate which "word" you wish to return from that string. You could then call this function from within similar `CASE` logic to return the first, second, third or fourth word in the name as required.

If you need to be able to handle 3 word names of the form `[First Name] [Middle Name] [Last Name]` (as I suspect you do), you'll probably want to build a list of the possible suffixes and use that list to determine whether each 3 word name has a suffix or middle name accordingly.

Comment: this sql doesn't parse

Comment: Runs fine for me on SQL Server 2014 SP2-CU11 and on [SQLFiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=7d9e2c6d-ad6c-4be9-86ad-67c1e7d11dd2).