# I'm having trouble separating the first name from the middle name column in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I created this syntax to separate first name, middle name and last name from a column called `invertornames`. Just to note that the investor names are in arabic and their middle names are more than 3 words. It worked fine but the first name is also being included in the middle name as you can see below in the image

[image]

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(investor_name, CHARINDEX(', ', investor_name) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', investor_name, CHARINDEX(', ', investor_name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(investor_name) + 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', investor_name, CHARINDEX(', ', investor_name) + 2) END - CHARINDEX(', ', investor_name) - 2)AS FirstName,                
    RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(investor_name,SUBSTRING(investor_name , 1, CHARINDEX(' ', investor_name) -1),''),REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(investor_name), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(investor_name))-1 ) ),''))) AS MiddleName,    
    RIGHT(investor_name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(investor_name))) AS LastName    
FROM
    investornames
```

If you need any data to try it please let me know.

Comment: did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619888/how-to-split-full-name-into-first-name-middle-name-last-name-and-suffix-in-tsq

Comment: @Ven yes i did and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I consider that First word is considered as `Firstname`, second word is considered as `MiddleName` and remaining word will considered as `LastName`.

For the case of `arabic names`. Software will not automatically detect that for which name calculation start from the front and for which it is taken in reverse. So I guess you need to maintain a flag for same.

In case of arabic name in the portion of `cte` use `reverse` to arrange them in left to right order instead of right to left order. And at the end use `reverse` function again to convert them into their original state.

Hope I am clear about what I am explaining. Sample code is following :-

```
; with cte as (
select 'Deepak kumar singh' as names
union
select 'Deep'
union 
select 'deep kumar'
union 
select 'Deepak kumar singh chandel')
SELECT 
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 1)) As [FirstName]
, Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) As [MiddleName]
, case when len( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 3)))>0 then substring ( names ,
charindex ( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ', names) + len(Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ') + 1
, len(names) - charindex ( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ', names) + len(Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ')) else null end
 As [LastName]
FROM  (Select names from cte ) As [x]
```

Result of above query is:

```
FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
Deep        NULL        NULL
deep        kumar       NULL
Deepak      kumar       singh
deepak      kumar       singh chandel
```

**Edit**

Updated this ans check this

```
; with cte as (
select ' شركة عبدالمحسن عبدالعزيزالبابطين ' as names
union
select 'شركة'
union 
select 'عبدالمحسن عبدالعزيز'
union 
select 'البابطين')
, ct as (
select RTRIM(LTRIM(names)) as Names from cte )
SELECT 
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 1)) As [FirstName]
, Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) As [MiddleName]
, case when len( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 3)))>0 then substring ( names ,
charindex ( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ', names) + len(Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ') + 1
, len(names) - charindex ( Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ', names) + len(Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(names), ' ', '.'), 2)) + ' ')) else null end
 As [LastName]
FROM  (Select names from ct ) As [x]
```

### Result

```
FirstName   MiddleName   LastName
????        ?????????    ?????????????????
????        NULL         NULL
????????    NULL         NULL
?????????   ?????????    NULL
```

Here I am expecting on place of `?` you'll get your result. BTW I've updated my query, have you tried this one. Just give one more try.

[image]

Comment: dear you posted image, how can i get data from your image...post them in text format.

Comment: its okk i understand i saw what you wrote above the code will try now @darkrob

Comment: i added what i replaced to your answer @darkrob

Comment: @samerg: updated my ans, since this font is not installed in my system so unable to verify. but seems like fine.

Comment: it gave me null values @darkrob

Comment: still same result it still gives me null values @darkrob

Comment: can you share your screenshot of whole screen.

Comment: if you run simple select on this in that case also this is giving same output format. I have no idea how these arabic values are stored and retrieved in sql database.

Comment: yes i know its really difficult to do this function with arabic values @darkrob